# I lost my albums and books

Tags: macos, software

I lost my albums and books in iPhoto and cannot retrieve them.  Is there anything I can do to retrieve these lost files?

Comment: What did you do to lose your Photos? It's easier to help if you describe what happened.

Answer (score 1):

If you've deleted them, you'll need to have a backup to restore the file from. If it's a laptop, hopefully you had local snapshots enabled, in which case you can go to the folder that contained your iPhoto library, enter Time Machine and restore the file.